# How to stop the treeview collaps event after mouse click

Tags: wpf, treeview

How can I stop the treeview collaps event after mouse click on TreeViewItem arrow (on view)?
I need to show my treeview expanded all time.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the Collapsed event in XAML:

```
<TreeView 
    Name="myTreeView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding dataSource}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Collapsed">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                            Duration="0" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TreeViewItem.IsExpanded)">
                                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>                            
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TreeView>
```

Comment: after removing the treeview.resources open tag this worked perfectly for me - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Collapsed event on the TreeViewItem to this:

```
private void TreeViewItem_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TreeViewItem).IsExpanded = true;
}
```

It doesn't prevent it from collapsing however, it just automatically expands it whenever it's collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Just [retemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) the `TreeViewItems` to not even have an arrow (and collapsible area).

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*(This is the bare minimum, you will want to have triggers to show the current selection if you need that)*

Comment: This will not prevent collapsing the item as you can still collapse it by double-clicking by default.

Comment: @kroimon: Various ways to intercept that, e.g. prevent mouse events from getting through using [`e.Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled.aspx).